# Java swing custom BasicButtonUI get it's buttons properties

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm new to Java, especially to swing and I was trying to make a button that has some custom property (color, number) and I wanted to make it a round button so my implementation was the following:

```
NumberButton testbutton = new NumberButton("0");
testbutton.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        if (c.isOpaque()) {
            g.setColor(testbutton.getColor());
            g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), 100, 100);
        }
        paint(g, c);
    }
});
mainPanel.add(testbutton);
```

The problem is that I want to make this BasicButtonUI generally callable custom class but I don't know how can I get from inside the "void update" function the outer testbutton's color property.

The custom NumberButton:

```
public class NumberButton extends JButton {
    private boolean pressState;
    private int number;
    private Color color;

    public NumberButton(String title) {
        super(title);

        this.pressState = false;
        this.number = 0;
        this.color = new Color(86, 86, 86);

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        this.setBackground(new Color(24, 25, 27));
        this.setAlignmentY(0.5F);
        this.setOpaque(true);

        this.addActionListener(actionEvent -> this.changePressState());
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void changePressState(){
        this.pressState = !this.pressState;
        if(this.pressState) {
            this.color = new Color(139, 239, 99, 166);
        } else {
            this.color = new Color(122, 154, 116);
        }
        this.number += 1;
        this.setText(String.valueOf(this.number));
     }
}
```

edit:
I tried creating a new class that extends to BasicButtonUI and the constructor takes one argument that can be set on call to the buttons color but than it doesn't changes it's color anymore:

```
public class RoundButtonUI extends BasicButtonUI {
    private Color color;

    RoundButtonUI(Color c) {
        super();
        this.color = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        if (c.isOpaque()) {
            g.setColor(this.color);
            g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 100, 100);
        }
        paint(g, c);
    }
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
NumberButton testbutton = new NumberButton("0");
testbutton.setUI(new RoundButtonUI(testbutton.getColor()));
```

edit #2:
One thing that fixed is that in the action that is changing the color of the button I call:

```
public void changePressState(){
    this.pressState = !this.pressState;
    if(this.pressState) {
        this.color = new Color(139, 239, 99, 166);
    } else {
        this.color = new Color(122, 154, 116);
    }
    this.number += 1;
    this.setText(String.valueOf(this.number));
    this.setUI(new RoundButtonUI(this.color));
}
```

but this is not a good solution just makes a mess so please if anybody have a better solution just tell!

The full source code is upp here to check:
[github](https://github.com/afkfish/Prog3-NHF)

Comment: You can not acces the testbutton. You have to put the color as paramter to the constructor of the BasicButtonUi

Comment: and do I do that with a class that extends to the BasicButtonUI and create a constructor for that wich takes the color as an argument and sets its color parameter to the given color and overrides the update method where the setColor gets the color from that created class?

Comment: don't call setUi directly (actually, you can't from outside the custom component, it's protected, isn't it -- oh no, AbstractButton exposes it, darn) : instead register your custom ui delegate with the uiManager and call updateUI, for an example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798631/how-to-determine-the-correct-ui-implementation-for-a-custom-component

Comment: all that said: this doesn't look like a use-case for a custom ui - just create and configure a plain button (f.i. via a factory). What do you _need_ the ui for?

Comment: only to change the rendering of it to fill round rectangle and its color